# Sharepoint WebPart visible only for Administrators

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am developing a application that contains a web parts in the home page.
This webparts are of lists and Libraries. The condition is that these webparts
must be visible only to the administrators and not the other users. I saw some 
solutions like set,

Modify Shared Web Part --> Advanced --> Target Audiences

but i donot find Modify Shared webpart in my application. I am using 
Sharepoint 2010. Any Ideas ? thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All make sure that You enabled option of  Audience targeting settings.

If Not then Follow this steps to enable it
Select the list or library that contains the item that you want to target.
On the list toolbar, click Settings, and then click List Settings or Document Library Settings.
Under General Settings, click Audience targeting settings.
Select the Enable audience targeting check box.

1.Select the list or library that contains the item that you want to target.
2.On the list toolbar, click Settings, and then click List Settings or Document Library Settings.
3.Under General Settings, click Audience targeting settings.
4.Select the Enable audience targeting check box.

After this check for the option of  Target Audiences in your web part .

Let me know the outcome.

Thanks

Comment: Hi

  I have done with the Target Audiences both on List and its Corresponding webpart.
But when i edit the webpart i could not find the Target Audiences. I also followed 
this link to setup target Audiences.

http://www.sharepointboost.com/blog/how-to-configure-the-target-audience-for-a-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-sites/

but i couldn't find site collection navigation as mentioned in this blog and also when 
i try to activate the sharepoint publishing infrastructure its showing me as 

Server Error in '/' Application.  


Thanks

Comment: Can you find the exact error message..?